# Flutter error while trying to start debugging

Tags: flutter, dart, upgrade

After installing firebase, cloud firestore I have an error....

[image]

Here is my buildgradle file

[image]

Also when I'm trying to upgrade my flutter to the newest version is an error that says:

```
 ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/mateuszptak/flutter.git/' not found
  Command: git fetch --tags
```

Comment: Do you get any issue after running `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: No, everything is ok